# Google App Engine Java search form

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine

I would like to create a form accompanied by a submit button that is redirected to a page in the format http://example.com/?search=Word+OtherWord (maybe through a GET request).  How would I set up a java class that first of all enables the user to go to such a page, and secondly, processes the parameters and renders html on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend learning Java Servlets / JSPs. They will help you accomplish this simple task.

Here is a [Hello World example](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-First-Servlets.html) which can help you to kick-start this task:

Here is a [Java Servlets / JSPs tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/)